# sqlsrv_connect not found with wampserver2.5 and dlls copied

Tags: php, sql

I have configured wampserver 2.5
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12

I want to connect to SQL Server with PHP.

i have read wampserver doesnt support by default, so i downloaded the dlls, php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll & php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and copied the same to ext folder of php(\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext) and added the extensions in php.ini file.
After that i have written a simple php file to check connect,

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

But i am getting error "**Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()**"

can i know why this error is still coming. How i can resolve the same.???

Comment: also i am using a 64bit wampserver

Comment: i have tried in 32bit wampserver also